# Constraints a view to the bottom of WKWebView.scollView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uikit, autolayout, wkwebview

I am trying to put a view at the bottom of the contentView of my WkWebView.scrollView, but it seems like the view always end up at the origin Y of 5000 or 8000 which is the random value of bound inside the WkWebView.

I tried setting frame, but resulted the same thing.

I wonder if you can actually put a view exactly after the contentView of the webView ended while still making the scrolling works?

```
self.webView.frame = self.view.bounds;
[self.webView.scrollView addSubview:self.myView];
self.myView.translateAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false;
[self.myView.topAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.webView.scrollView.subViews.lastObject.bottomAnchor].active = true;
[self.myView.bottomAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.webView.scrollView.bottomAnchor].active = true;
[self.myView.widthAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.view.widthAnchor].active = true;
```

Comment: Have you tried `contentLayoutGuide`?

Answer (score 0):

A `WKWebView` is not as simple as a scroll view holding processed html. If you use `Debug View Hierarchy` you'll see how complex it can be.

I would suggest:

- add the "bottomView" to the web view (**not** to its scroll view)
- constrain the bottom of the bottomView to the bottom of the web view's frame
- implement `scrollViewDidScroll` and update the `.constant` to position the bottomView

You'll want to keep bottomView hidden until the page has loaded, set `clipsToBounds` on the web view so the bottomView is not visible outside the frame, and set the web view's `.scrollView.contentInset` to allow for the extra space to show the bottomView.

Here's a quick example, using this page as the web view's url:

**ViewController.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController
@end
```

**ViewController.m**

```
#import <WebKit/WebKit.h>
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController () <UIScrollViewDelegate, WKNavigationDelegate>
{
    WKWebView *webView;
    UILabel *bottomView;
    NSLayoutConstraint *bottomC;
    CGFloat bottomViewHeight;
}
@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    
    webView = [WKWebView new];

    webView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    [self.view addSubview:webView];

    bottomView = [UILabel new];
    bottomView.text = @"Bottom View";
    bottomView.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    bottomView.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor;

    bottomView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    [webView addSubview:bottomView];
    
    bottomViewHeight = 60.0;
    
    UILayoutGuide *g = self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide;
    
    [NSLayoutConstraint activateConstraints:@[
        
        [webView.topAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:g.topAnchor constant:40.0],
        [webView.leadingAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:g.leadingAnchor constant:8.0],
        [webView.trailingAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:g.trailingAnchor constant:-8.0],
        [webView.bottomAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:g.bottomAnchor constant:-40.0],
        
        [bottomView.leadingAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:webView.leadingAnchor constant:0.0],
        [bottomView.trailingAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:webView.trailingAnchor constant:0.0],
        [bottomView.heightAnchor constraintEqualToConstant:bottomViewHeight],

    ]];
    
    // this will be changed when the webView scrolls
    bottomC = [bottomView.bottomAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:webView.bottomAnchor constant:0.0];
    bottomC.active = YES;

    // we need to allow the web view to scroll up enough to "add" the bottom view at the bottom
    webView.scrollView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, bottomViewHeight, 0);

    // delegates
    webView.scrollView.delegate = self;
    webView.navigationDelegate = self;

    // we don't want bottom view showing outside the bounds of the web view
    webView.clipsToBounds = YES;

    // start with bottom view hidden
    bottomView.hidden = YES;
    
    NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString: @"https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76536415/constraints-a-view-to-the-bottom-of-wkwebview-scollview"];
    NSURLRequest *request = [[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL: url
                                                  cachePolicy: NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy
                                              timeoutInterval: 5];
    [webView loadRequest: request];
    
}

- (void)webView:(WKWebView *)webView didFinishNavigation:(WKNavigation *)navigation {
    // webview has "finished loading"
    bottomC.constant = webView.scrollView.contentSize.height - webView.scrollView.contentOffset.y - webView.frame.size.height + 60.0;
    bottomView.hidden = NO;
}
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    // change the bottomView's bottom constraint constant so it moves with the
    //  bottom of the web view's content
    bottomC.constant = scrollView.contentSize.height - scrollView.contentOffset.y - webView.frame.size.height + 60.0;
}

@end
```

It will be a pretty tall page, but once you scroll all the way to the bottom you will see the green label:

[image]

Note: as I'm sure you know, web pages can be very dynamic, doing things like adding more content as you scroll. So, this may or may not be suitable -- or may need some additional logic to handle dynamic content.